# Info:Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I was using my UDF in my pig script this morning without any problem. But now when I try I receive this error message:

Info:Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

I guess it means I miss a hbase jar in my classpath!! But I change nothing!

How can I fix that?

An example of how I can add the hbase jar will be great!!

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by registering hbase in my pig script.

REGISTER path/to/hbase/jar

In my case

REGISTER /usr/lib/hbase/hbase.jar;

Answer (score 0):

Add hbase jar into class path.
If you are running it form command line then use java -cp to add jar in class path.

Comment: Please can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add HBase jar file into your class path. 
You can also seee Hbase installation stuff at this site :

http://www.improgrammer.net/tag/hbase/